# Convert touch in ViewGroup coordinates to touch in child View coordinates

Tags: android, view, touch, coordinates, viewgroup

In an App I am working on, I have a custom ViewGroup with some custom child Views. When I get a touch in this custom ViewGroup I would like to convert the coordinates of this touch to coordinates with respect to one of these child Views. Is there any API for this? Or do I need to make my own utility function?